# Call device under local network with dynamic ip through hostname

Tags: ip, dhcp

The thing is that I have an arduino connected to my network, but it's under DHCP, which means it constantly changes it's ip. When I call it I use it's assigned ip, example: 192.168.1.XX/anycommand. So I'd like to know if there's a way to call my Arduino but using it's hostname instead of ip, so I won't have to check it's ip everytime I try to call it. Something like http://myarduino/anycommand

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on how the hostname is broadcast (if at all).

However, there are a few simple steps to achieve what you want. First of all, you need to add a static entry for your Arduino in whatever is acting as a DHCP server. This is most likely your router, and most routers support static leases. Once this is done, there are two main approaches.

1. Add a DNS entry in your router (presuming that your LAN has a router acting as a gateway to the internet). How this is done depends entirely on your router (and whether it supports it at all).
2. Add an entry in your hosts-file. This is OS dependant, but all OSes have one, but in different locations, and under different names. Basically. Luckily, it turns out that wikipedia has a nice list of OSes and the name/location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system